# Is there any git appliance that support gitorious?

Tags: git, gitorious, appliance

I have tried [TurnKey Linux Revision Control](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/revision-control) appliance and it has gitweb cgi as web interface.

I am looking for appliance similar to turnkey linux that has git and gitorious as web web interface.  The deployment of gitorious (e.g.: [Setting up Gitorious on your own server](http://cjohansen.no/en/ruby/setting_up_gitorious_on_your_own_server)) is not an easy job.

Comment: Fast-forward to 2013: http://getgitorious.com/virtual-appliance

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest thing you can come up with is BitNami, potentially I don't know everything that is available in this area though. I know there is a way to set up Git with it, but it seems people are still trying to convince them to support Gitorious.

Comment: A Gitorious Stack now is available for download http://bitnami.org/stack/gitorious You can also download a virtual machine or deploy it directly on Amazon EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm stating the obvious here, but have you considered getting support directly from the source at [gitorious](http://gitorious.com/local_install)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a long [thread on the Turnkey Linux forum](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/general/20100810/tklpatch-gitorious) with [patches for creating your own appliance](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/general/20100810/tklpatch-gitorious#comment-8480).

The Gitorious team also [sells one](http://gitorious.com/local_install) for $5,000 for the first year and $2,500 each following year.

Comment: We've been using the Gitorious TKL appliance for the last year quite successfully. First as a VM running in VirtualBox on an iMac, and now as a dedicated Linux box.